# Avoiding dynamic RegEx creation in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, optimization, regex

This function's job is to replace several text smilies, e.g. `:D`, `:)`, `:love` with the appropriate smiley image.
In my opinion my code has several issues, yet the main problem is that *a lot* of quite similar regexes are created dynamically: one for each different smilie replaced.
As you might expect, replacing smilies in a text is a job done kindly often, so this is indeed code that is executed a lot of time, therefore I think optimizing that makes sense.

Well, why didn't I just call `text.replace()`?
**I don't want the smilies to be replaced if they are enclosed by backticks: `**

```
var replaceTextSmilies = function() {
    var smiliesShortcut = {};
    smiliesShortcut[':)'] = 'smile.png';
    /* adding much more */

    var smiliesWordy = {};
    smiliesWordy[':angry'] = 'angry.png';
    /* adding much more */



    function escapeRegExp(str) {
        return str.replace(/([.?*+^$[\]\\(){}|-])/g, "\\$1");
    }

    return function(text) {
        Object.keys(smiliesWordy).forEach(function(entry) {
            var image = '<img src="img/smilies/' + smiliesWordy[entry] + '"/>';

            if(text.indexOf(entry) !== -1) {
                var regex = new RegExp('('+ escapeRegExp(entry) +')(?=(?:(?:[^`]*`){2})*[^`]*$)', 'g');
                text = text.replace(regex, image);
            }
        });
        Object.keys(smiliesShortcut).forEach(function(entry) {
            var image = '<img src="img/smilies/' + smiliesShortcut[entry] + '"/>';

            if(text.indexOf(entry) !== -1) {
                var regex = new RegExp('('+ escapeRegExp(entry) +')(?=(?:(?:[^`]*`){2})*[^`]*$)', 'g');
                text = text.replace(regex, image);
            }
        });
        return text;
    };
}();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can store the regex as part of the smily metadata.

```
var replaceTextSmilies = function() {
    var smiliesShortcut = {};
    smiliesShortcut[':)'] = {
        img : 'smile.png'
    };
    /* adding much more */

    var smiliesWordy = {};
    smiliesWordy[':angry'] = {
        img : 'angry.png'
    };
    /* adding much more */

    addRegex(smiliesShortcut);
    addRegex(smiliesWordy);

    function escapeRegExp(str) {
        return str.replace(/([.?*+^$[\]\\(){}|-])/g, "\\$1");
    }

    function addRegex(smilies) {
        Object.keys(smilies).forEach(function(smily) {
            smilies[smily].regex = new RegExp('(' + escapeRegExp(smily) + ')(?=(?:(?:[^`]*`){2})*[^`]*$)', 'g');
        });
    }

    function replace(text, smilies) {
        Object.keys(smilies).forEach(function(entry) {
            var image = '<img src="img/smilies/' + smilies[entry].img + '"/>';

            if (text.indexOf(entry) !== -1) {
                text = text.replace(smilies[entry].regex, image);
            }
        });
        return text;
    }

    return function(text) {
        text = replace(text, smiliesWordy);
        text = replace(text, smiliesShortcut);
        return text;
    };
}();
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/DVme2/)

Note: You can make it even better if you can manually create the regex and assign them instead of using `addRegex()` like

```
    smiliesShortcut[':)'] = {
        img : 'smile.png',
        regex: /<the regex>/
    };
```